# How to enable Spring batch to be monitored in Elastic APM?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-batch, apm

Currently spring boot micorservices are enabled in Elastic APM. We can also trace at method level and DB queries are shown.
But Spring batch job(Spring boot based) does not show any method level details and Oracle transaction details.
Does anything needs to be explicitly configured in Elastic APM for Spring batch applications.

Answer (score 0):

currently elastic-apm-agent support natively Quartz framework(since 1.8). If you use it, instrumentation should work. But you should add your packages to `application_packages`.
It would be good if you can share mini-demo project. And I can reproduce your problem locally.
Information from [supported-technologies-details](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/supported-technologies-details.html)

```
The agent instruments the execute method of any class implementing org.quartz.Job, as well as the executeInternal method of any class extending org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean, and creates a transaction with the type scheduled, representing the job execution

NOTE: only classes from the quartz-jobs dependency will be instrumented automatically. For the instrumentation of other jobs the package must be added to the application_packages parameter.
```